# Go lang multi waitgroup and timer stops in the end

Tags: go

i have written the following code in order to run until someone exit the program manually.

it does is

- ----- check if the exists every 1 second
- ----- if available then read the file and print the file content line by line

for this i have first call a function from the main
and then i call a waitgroup and call a function again from there to do the aforementioned tasks.

please check if i have written the source code correctly as im a newbi on GO

plus this only runs once and stop... i want to it keep alive and see if the file exsists

please help me

```
 package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    mainfunction()
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------

func mainfunction() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go filecheck(&wg)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("Program finished \n")

}

func filecheck(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    for range time.Tick(time.Second * 1) {
        fmt.Println("Foo")

        var wgi sync.WaitGroup
        wgi.Add(1)

        oldName := "test.csv"
        newName := "testi.csv"

        if _, err := os.Stat(oldName); os.IsNotExist(err) {
            fmt.Printf("Path does not exsist \n")
        } else {
            os.Rename(oldName, newName)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            looping(newName, &wgi)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Test complete \n")
        wgi.Wait()
        wg.Done()
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    }
}

func looping(newName string, wgi *sync.WaitGroup) {
    file, _ := os.Open(newName)
    r := csv.NewReader(file)
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        var Date = record[0]
        var Agent = record[1]
        var Srcip = record[2]
        var Level = record[3]

        fmt.Printf("Data: %s Agent: %s Srcip: %s Level: %s\n", Date, Agent, Srcip, Level)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Test complete 2 \n")
    wgi.Done()

    fmt.Printf("for ended")
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need any goroutine here unless you are only practicing. If you are practicing you also don't need the second wait group inside the func filecheck, usually waitgroups would be used outside the method unless that method is calling another goroutine

Comment: @Totoro any recommended way i can write this? can u adjust the code if you don't mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you have this in the loop:

```
    wg.Done()
```

Which makes the main goroutine proceed to exit as soon as the file is read once.

---

The longer answer is that you're not using wait groups correctly here, IMHO. For example there's absolutely no point in passing a `WaitGroup` into `looping`.

It's not clear what your code is trying to accomplish - you certainly don't need any goroutines to just perform the task you've specified - it can all be gone with no concurrency and thus simpler code.

Comment: so your suggesting this all is run on the main function?

Comment: @checkmate: that would be the simplest solution, so yes. Unless you have more complicated requirements in your "real life" scenario, in which case it's probably a different question.

Comment: Hey thanx mate.... it solved the issue i had.... i actually need waitgroup in the actual solution.... but it require only in one point. thnx